# Finding Percentile of a calculated measure in PowerPivot / DAX

Tags: dax, powerpivot

A table that is similar to the data set I am working on (although much simpler) is below that I would like to calculate some measures on and then find the percentiles of the measures.

```
Table Name: Data
Owner  AgeRating   OtherRating
  A        1            2
  A        4            4
  A        4            6
  B        3            3
  B        3            9
  B        7            4
  C        8            8
  C        4            2
```

**First** - A little background: I start by taking an average of the ratings (By Owner) and then normalize all ratings by dividing each rating by the maximum owner's rating - This creates the measure I would like to take the percentile of:

```
NormAgeRating=
average(Data[AgeRating])/
calculate(
    maxx(
        SUMMARIZE(Data,[Owner],"avg",average([AgeRating]))
       ,[avg]
    )
   ,all(Data[owner])
)
```

I have a pivot table with Rows being the owner which then looks like

```
Owner NormAgeRating
 A        .5
 B       .72
 C        1
```

Now for the **question**:
I would like to get the .33 `percentile.inc` of the new `NormAgeRating`. I would like to use this to classify each owner into groups (<=33%ile or > 33%ile)
This is what I am trying to get to:

```
Owner NormAgeRating   33%ile   classification
 A        .5            .64     bottom
 B       .72            .64     top
 C        1             .64     top
```

I have tried this with no success and many other variation with different groupby's etc. and continually get the wrong value:

```
33%ile=percentilex.inc(all(data[owner]),[NormAgeRating],0.33)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Update:
When I try `sumx` `countx` and `averagex` in the form:

```
=
averagex(
    SUMMARIZE(
        all(Data[Owner]),
        [Owner],
        "risk",[NormAgeRating]),
    [risk]
)
```

I am getting the right values, so I am not sure why using `percentilex.inc/exc` would produce the wrong values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PERCENTILEX (and all iterator functions) operates row by row on the table in the first argument. Therefore, you need that table to be at the desired granularity before you try to compute the percentile, which means you need to summarize `Data[Owner]` so that you have a unique row per owner rather than iterating over the raw column.

Keeping this in mind, both measures can be written similarly:

```
NormAgeRating = 
DIVIDE (
    AVERAGE ( Data[AgeRating] ),
    MAXX (
        SUMMARIZE (
            ALL ( Data[Owner] ),
            Data[Owner],
            "Avg", AVERAGE ( Data[AgeRating] )
        ),
        [Avg]
    )
)

33%ile = 
PERCENTILEX.INC (
    SUMMARIZE (
        ALL ( Data[Owner] ),
        Data[Owner],
        "Risk", [NormAgeRating]
    ),
    [Risk],
    0.33
)
```

Comment: Hi Alexis - Thanks for the response. I tried this exactly and the column ended up empty with no values. See the update above, I was able to use the same method just with averagex and it provided me with the right answer. Is there some limitation to PercentileX, that I am not aware of?

Comment: It worked for me when I replicated your example data. Perhaps there's something going with your PBIX that isn't apparent from what you've shown. https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6je0.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove blank rows form the summarized table as the percentilex consideres your blank rows also for calculation and returns blank when you pull that measure. where as plain Percentile ingnore blank rows.I have used filter function to remove black rows from summary table created.

```
DIVIDE (
    AVERAGE ( Data[AgeRating] ),
    MAXX (
        SUMMARIZE (
            ALL ( Data[Owner] ),
            Data[Owner],
            "Avg", AVERAGE ( Data[AgeRating] )
        ),
        [Avg]
    )
)

VAR __table_blank_Removed =
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZE (
            ALL ( Data[Owner] ),
            Data[Owner],
            "Risk", [NormAgeRating]
        ),
        [Risk] <> BLANK ()
    )

RETURN
    PERCENTILEX.INC (
        __table_blank_Removed,
        [Risk],
        0.33
    )
```